# Workflow rule formula

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a workflow rule (field update) so that when 'Work Country' (Work_Country__c) at the top of the page is entered, this will automatically fill in a field also called 'Work Country' (Work_Country2__c) further down the page. I am not sure how to write the formula for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a formula field (Work_Country2__c)type text and on formula pane just select the field from which you want to capture the value (in your case Work_Country__c). When the record is saved the formula field will be updated.